# How to add album art to multiple tracks with Rythmbox?

Tags: mp3, mp3-player

I wanted to add a cover art for a mp3 album I have on my laptop.

I do use Rythmbox, but I'm unable to add a cover art for multiple mp3 files of the same album and I have to do it one by one.

What can I do?

Comment: I don't know about Rhythm Box but I use `Kid3` to add album art to multiple tracks at one time. More info at: https://kid3.sourceforge.io/